# How should I improve my query performance?

Tags: sql, performance, indexing, db2

I have created a table with a couple of columns.

MyTable

- Column1 -> RecordId (int)
- Column2 -> Title (varchar)
- Column3 -> Shortname (varchar)
- Column4 ->  (varchar)
- Column5 -> varchar

  ...

  ...
- Column10 -> varchar

I am not joining this table with any other tables. I have 4 rows of data in the table.

When I am querying for title, shortname for a particular RecordId, the query seems to be too slow. It nearly takes 7 seconds to load the page.

I haven't used any indexing on my tables. Can you please suggest how do I improve my table/query performance?

I am making db connection from my jsp in order to display the query results in the listbox.

My code looks something like this- 
conn= DataObjectConnectionPool.getInstance().getConnection();
prepStmt = conn.prepStmt("select title,shortname from MyTable where RecordId=1");

Comment: You have to show us the code you are using.

Comment: You mention a page. Is this query part of something larger? It seems unlikely that this is causing the performance issue. Can you try running the query directly on the database to see how long it takes?

Comment: Which fields are you mainly using to select rows? They will be your best candidates for indexing.

Comment: First i think its better have primary key for the table you created. i am assuming you already have that. second, "It nearly takes 7 seconds to load the page." Try running it directly to see how long it takes.. it may be something on the page that causing it too load page longer.

Comment: @Laurence, I am making db connection from my jsp in order to display the query results in the listbox.

My code looks something like this- conn= DataObjectConnectionPool.getInstance().getConnection(); prepStmt = conn.prepStmt("select title,shortname from MyTable where RecordId=1");

Comment: There's definitely something weird going on here.  With only 4 rows, I can pretty much guarantee you that you're _never_ going to be using an index - the optimizer will just do a table scan (and if this table is heavily used, probably keep the entire thing in memory too).  What kind of hardware/software (server) are you running this on?  See about getting a profiler running - all good servers should have one.  And could we get the actual DDL for your table (especially for things like field lengths).

Comment: The DDL runs in few milli seconds. Also, the RecordId is primary key. Not only in this page, any query in my jsp is taking long to load. Also I have unique index for shortname field.

Comment: The DDL runs in few milli seconds. Also, the RecordId is primary key. Not only in this page, any query in my jsp is taking long to load. Also I have unique index for shortname field.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a **primary key** on RecordId.

This will have the side-effect of creating an index on that column.

BUT

If your page is loading in 7 seconds, and you only have 4 rows of data in the table, then the problem is almost certainly not in the DBMS.

Comment: I defintely have primary key on RecordId, but I don't think that is the issue here. If the problem is not in DBMS, then where could it be?

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no point to creating indexes on a table with 4 rows.  If you would like to see the time in the dbms for the execution of your query,  grab some data from the package cache after you run the query.

```
select num_exec_with_metrics, total_act_time,  pool_read_time
  from table(mon_get_pkg_cache_stmt(null,null,null,null))
```

There are 100 other columns in that table function involving different types of waits, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Basically you are using this sql query in your code:

```
select title,shortname from MyTable where RecordId=1
```

From the database end you can speed up the query by creating index on the `RecordID` column and then doing runstats ==>

```
create index MyIndex on MyTable (RecordID) Compress yes Allow reverse scans;
runstats on table Mytable and indexes all shrlevel change;
```